# HTML5 Web Audio API has strange noise when playing PCM data with AudioBuffer

Tags: javascript, html, audio, web-audio-api

I'm trying to use HTML5 Web Audio to play notes buffer by buffer, but I found there's strange, loud, undesired noise when the note starts and ends. Is there anyone who knows how to get rid of it? Thanks!

I have a working example here, and i've repeated this note so you'll here the noise clearly:

https://jsfiddle.net/charrli/ca48tj23/5/

The code is like the following. I'm generating sin wave:

```
   var audioContext = new AudioContext();
var audioBuffer;// = new AudioBuffer();
var audioBufferArray;//: number[];
var audioBufferArrayIndex;//: number;
var frameCount = 8192;
    audioBuffer = audioContext.createBuffer(1, frameCount, 44100);

function play(){
    //audioContext = new AudioContext();
      audioBufferArray = this.audioBuffer.getChannelData(0);
        audioBufferArrayIndex = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < frameCount; i++) {
            audioBufferArray[i] = Math.sin((i%168)/168.0*Math.PI*2);
        }
        var source = this.audioContext.createBufferSource();
                    // set the buffer in the AudioBufferSourceNode
            source.buffer = this.audioBuffer;
                    // connect the AudioBufferSourceNode to the
                    // destination so we can hear the sound
        source.connect(this.audioContext.destination);
                    // start the source playing
        source.start();
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioParam/linearRampToValueAtTime

Answer (score 0):

You need to smooth start/end of wave to prevent clicks

add this:

> ```
>   for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
>     audioBufferArray[i] = audioBufferArray[i]*i/100;//fade in
>     audioBufferArray[frameCount-i-1] = audioBufferArray[frameCount-i-1]*i/100;//fade out
>     }
> ```

see
https://jsfiddle.net/sss1024/ca48tj23/7/